# Installation Problem of the R package "devtools"

Tags: r, devtools

When I try to install the `install.packages("devtools")` package, I got the following error:

> '"D:\Program Install\R & RStudio\R-4.2.2\R-4.2.2/bin/x64/Rterm.exe"'
> is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program
> or batch file. Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
> ‘pkgload’ had non-zero exit status

How do I solve this? I am using windows 10

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use a uniform and the correct formatted address. In windows, it is common to use a backslash (`\`) to define a file path but in R, you have to reverse that and change the backslash to slash (`/`). Here is an example:

```
# In Windows #
C:\Users\Username\Documents\R\win-library\4.1
# In R #
C:/Users/Username/Documents/R/win-library/4.1
```

Hope it helps.